# Object reference not set to an instance of an object C# class

Tags: c#, class, interface

I keep getting this error while trying to call a DataAccess layer in my C# windows form application.

In my design, I have used an interface and a class.

The inteface called iDataAccess, and the code inside it looks like this:

IDataAccess.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
public interface IDataAccess
{

    object GetScalar(string sql);
    DataTable GetDataTable(string sql);
    int InsOrUpdOrDel(string sql);
}
```

The class called DataAccess and the code inside it looks something like this:
DataAccess.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public class DataAccess : IDataAccess  
{
    public static string CONNSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDbConnect"].ConnectionString;

    public DataAccess()

    {

    }

  public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNSTR);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Now, in form.cs code I want to create an object of the mentioned class. For this reason, I have tried two different ways, but none of them worked for me, as shown below:

`IDataAccess _idataAccess = new DataAccess();`    // I get instance failure error

`IDataAccess _idataAccess = null;`   // Error: Object reference not set to instance of an object

can anyone give me an idea about this problem, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "// I get instance failure error" ? what error occurs when you create a new instance of DataAccess?

Comment: Where does the debugger stop, if you ask it to stop on exceptions being thrown? It *might* be because `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDbConnect"]` is returning `null` which is implicitly part of the type's static constructor.

Comment: This is the instance error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)

Comment: It's your connection string. What does your connection string look like?

Comment: I checked the connection string, now I get the same error ( Object reference not set to instance of an object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have SqlDbConnect

```
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDbConnect"].ConnectionString;
```

in your configurations.

make sure that this line returns what you expect it to.

And your code can't compile unless you implement these methods in your dataaccess class

```
public object GetScalar(string sql)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int InsOrUpdOrDel(string sql)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: I do have it, but do you think it can't read it that is why I get the first error? "instant connection error".

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that caused that error

Answer (score 1):

```
IDataAccess _idataAccess = new DataAccess();
```

will work but you need to implement

```
object GetScalar(string sql);
```

and

```
int InsOrUpdOrDel(string sql);
```

in

```
DataAccess
```

as follows

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess  
{
    public static string CONNSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDbConnect"].ConnectionString;

    public DataAccess()

    {

    }

  object GetScalar(string sql)
  {
      return new object();
  }

  int InsOrUpdOrDel(string sql)
  {
      return 1;
  }

  public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNSTR);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```